# How to open JInternalFrame when jbutton click

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jFrame ob=new jFrame();
    ob.setVisible(true);
}
```

This opned new frame.now I want to open jInternalFrame as the same way.I tried many like

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JInternalFrame1 ob=new  JInternalFrame1();
    ob.setVisible(true);
}
```

No error occured and nothing happen. Any possible way to click the jbutton and JInternalFrame open.

Comment: I find this example. It show you how to open a JInternalFrame from a JMenuItem. I hope that help you to resolve your problem :  http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-jinternalframe-class-example

Answer (score 1):

`JInternalFrame` can't be displayed independently as like Frame.
    First add the internal frame to a frame. then try `setVisible(true)`. like...

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test InternalJFrame");
        frame.add(new MyInternalFrame());
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

(OR) the best way is to use `JDesktopPane` in a `Frame`.
create a `JDesktopPane` and add it to a `Frame`. and then add the `JInternalFrame` to the desktop pane.
    try to set it to visible when you click on button or any action that you want to perform. Hope its clear for you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
when we want to add JinternalFrame to a JFrame we have to add JDesktopPane first and after that we add the Jinternalframe on it
```

try this code..it works :)

```
  desk = new JDesktopPane(); 
  this.add(desk);
  private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  JInternalFrame1 ob=new  JInternalFrame1();
 desk.add(ob);
 }
```

Comment: Can you please add a rationale: Why should the problem be resolved this way?